# Javascript reduce function error

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to play with the Reduce function in JavaScript. What I am trying to achieve can be easily done via the filter function but I am trying to do it via Reduce.

I am trying to retrieve all the people where the age is greater or equal to 18 years and store the result in an array

```
var people = [
{ name: "John", age: 16 },
{ name: "Thomas", age: 20 },
{ name: "Smith", age: 18 },
{ name: "Jessy", age: 17 },
];
var arr = [];
var output = people.reduce(function(arr,ppl){
if(ppl.age >= 18)
    return(arr.push(ppl));
},arr);
console.log(output);
```

However when I run this snippet, I get an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". I am not sure where do I need to define the arr (array where I need to store the output)

Comment: `arr` is going to be the function’s last return value. Are you always returning a value?

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the `Array`. You need to `push` then return `arr`. If the age is < 18 you return `undefined` ...

Comment: Understood, Thank you very much

Comment: One of the beauties of `reduce()` is that you don't need an outer var. Just start with `} []);`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

you should `return arr`,not `return arr.push(ppl)` because `[].push(3)` return `1`(new length of `[]` ) not `[3]`.And `reduce` works with `accumulator` which in this case the `accumulator` is `arr`.So,you should `return arr` not  `return (arr.push(ppl))`;

```js
var people = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 16
  },
  {
    name: "Thomas",
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: "Smith",
    age: 18
  },
  {
    name: "Jessy",
    age: 17
  },
];
var arr = [];
var output = people.reduce(function(arr, ppl) {
  if (ppl.age >= 18)
    (arr.push(ppl));
  return arr;

}, arr);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely works. Please help me understand whats wrong with my code. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Manish,because you     return(arr.push(ppl)); you should return arr

Comment: _"because `[].push(1)` return `1` not `[1]`"_ Because `.push()` returns the new length of the array (and not the pushed element)

Answer (score 0):

```
 return(arr.push(ppl));
```

As `arr.push` returns the new length of the array, it will return a number. So at the next iteration `arr` will be a number, and you cant push to that. So you need to pass on the array:

```
 const output = people.reduce((arr, person) => person.age > 17 ? arr.concat(person): arr, []);
```

That works as `arr.concat` returns an array.

Comment: …and more importantly, in the `else` case nothing was returned at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.concat to push to an array and return it, and put that in a ternary operator:

```js
let people=[{name:"John",age:16},{name:"Thomas",age:20},{name:"Smith",age:18},{name:"Jessy",age:17}]

let output = people.reduce((arr,ppl) => {
    return ppl.age >= 18 ? arr.concat(ppl) : arr
},[])

console.log(output)
```